# Empty grid when using INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, join, datagridview

I am trying to get a student's data and display it in a gridview in C#. If I just run the following query, it gets fine results from a single table named student.

```
conn.Open();

da = new SqlDataAdapter("select sID as 'Student ID',  sFirstName as 'First Name', sLastName as 'Last Name', sGender as 'Gender', sDOB as 'Date Of Birth', sSession as 'Session', sClassRollNo as 'Class Roll Number', sAdmissionDate as 'Admission Date', sGuardianFirstName as 'Guardian First Name', sGuardianLastName as 'Guardian Last Name', sGuardianRelationship as 'Guardian Relationship', sGuardianOccupation as 'Guardian Occupation', sGuardianCity as 'City', sAddress as 'Address', sEmail as 'Email', sMobile as 'Mobile No', sPhone as 'Phone' from student", conn);
```

And when I try to join student table with class table and show data it gets me nothing but empty grid.

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT student.sID as 'Student ID from Student Table', student.sFirstName as 'Student Name from Student Table', Classes.class as 'Class from Class Table' FROM student INNER JOIN classes ON classes.sID=student.sID", conn);

ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "student");
gvSearchStudent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
conn.Close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If it returned an empty grid then it is likely there were 0 join matches. Try the same query in SSMS.

Comment: Do you get something if you run that query in SSMS?  Without seeing the underlying data, impossible to know whether the result you get is correct or not.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'student'. . . . it gives me this when i run this SELECT student.sID, student.sFirstName, classes.class FROM student INNER JOIN classes ON student.sID=classes.sID in Ms SQL. . . . sorry Im New.

Comment: I'm not familiar with connecting to a database and running an sql from c#, but are you sure student exists as a table in whatever database you are connecting to?

Comment: @user3615189 Did you ever get this figured out and were any of the comments/answers here helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments on the question pretty well answer the question, but I will try and pull them together here and add my own thoughts so that this post has an "answer".

As user2864740 and Eric J. mention, the best way to debug this query will be to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and experiment with your query to see what the underlying data is.  You have already verified that

```
SELECT * FROM Student -- I'm using * here as a short cut, 
                      -- you correctly specified the columns you wanted
```

works.  That tells us that your connection string is (most likely) correct (i.e. you are going to the correct database) and that the `Student` table exists.  The next thing you should do is

```
SELECT * FROM Classes
```

to verify that your `Classes` table exists and contains data.  If not, you know why you are getting 0 rows back.

Next, visually scan over the data you got back--do you see any entries in the `Student.sID` column that match any entries in the `Classes.sID` column?  Again, if not, then you know why you are getting 0 rows back.

Let me take just a moment and ask you to do a sanity check.  Are you sure there is a `Classes.sID` column and that it is a foreign key reference to `Student.sID`?  It seems like this could be a mistake because it would mean that each class could only have 1 student (unless `Classes` is a linking table to something else that actually represents a class).

If you have followed the troubleshooting this far and there does not appear to be any reason for failure, then the underlying data shouldn't be the problem.

Looking at your comment,

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'student'.

I can't help but wonder--are you sure you didn't misspell "student" somewhere?  To help prevent spelling errors, you can use table aliases like so:

```
SELECT 
    s.sID as 'Student ID from Student Table', 
    s.sFirstName as 'Student Name from Student Table', 
    c.class as 'Class from Class Table' 
FROM student s
    INNER JOIN classes c ON c.sID=s.sID
```

If you are still having trouble, then consider stripping the query down to make it as basic and syntactically simple as possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
    INNER JOIN classes ON classes.sID=student.sID
```

and then build it up from there.